# Could not parse the remainder: '\u2018polls:detail\u2019' from '\u2018polls:detail\u2019

Tags: django-templates

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href=“{% url ‘polls:detail’ question.id %}”>{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% end for %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Couldn't figure out what went wrong. Feel like it might be space. Need help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this similar query [[How to resolve TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018436/how-to-resolve-templatesyntaxerror-could-not-parse-the-remainder-error][1])

'polls:detail' should be enclosed in single or double quotes (ability to do so depends on the fonts installed on local m/c).